# How to append two associative arrays with same key

Tags: php

[image: I have two arrays with same key names and some times value may be same. I want to append these two arrays into one new array. I have added screen shot of these array. I found array_merge but I saw it overrides instead of append. Is there any function in php to do this or I have write custome function.]

I have two arrays with same key names and some times value may be same. I want to append these two arrays into one new array. I have added screen shot of these array. I found array_merge but I saw it overrides instead of append.  Is there any function in php to do this or I have write custome function.

Comment: So you want the resulting array to have the same key more than once ?

Comment: Or, you'd want the `lat` and `lng`-fields to be put in the `latitude` and `longitude` fields, etc.? (uniform keys)

Comment: @FabienMénager I want the new array will have at index 0 the one old array and at index 1 another old array. I need a multidimensional array

Comment: Rather than trying to express in words what is best left to code... can you post an example of the desired output array as well - Also SO code blocks are much easier to read than images of code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```